# ContentMode changes in uiimageview after draw

Tags: swift, uiimageview, core-graphics

I have been following Ray Wenderlics's tutorial on how to create a basic draw app.

Ive got it working perfectly except for when I draw the content mode changes on the uiimageview.

I've set it to aspectFill in storyboard and applied an image

I think the problem is in my touches ended method

```
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        // draw a single point
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
    }

    // Merge tempImageView into mainImageView
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size)
    mainImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mainImageView.frame.size.width, height: mainImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: 1.0)
    tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mainImageView.frame.size.width, height: mainImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: opacity)
    mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    tempImageView.image = nil


}
```

it changes the content mode to what appears to be scaleToFill or Scale to fit?

Does anybody know how I change this?

regards

Thomas

**Update**

Thanks Matt for your direction

Ive added the following code

```
  let imageSize = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: (mainImageView.image?.size)!, insideRect: mainImageView.frame)

    mainImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width , height: imageSize.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: 1.0)
    tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: opacity)
    mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

I think I'm on the right track but the image is now resizing to aspect fit rather then aspect fill.

Comment: Any update? Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The content mode of the image view is not changing. (You can test that easily, just by examining its `contentMode`, which doesn't happen anywhere in your code.)

The problem is the way you draw! You are drawing an image, `mainImageView.image`, into a rect `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mainImageView.frame.size.width, height: mainImageView.frame.size.height)`. That stretches the image to fit that rect exactly — resulting in the stretching behavior that you're complaining about.

In other words, *you* are saying "Scale this image to fill this rect", and that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the changes required to prevent this stretching?

Comment: @DoesData Unclear what you mean. There is no "issue" here; the code is doing exactly what the OP asked it to. If you have a new question, don't poke at it in the comments; ask a real question about _your_ problem.

Comment: I understand the code is doing what he told it to do.  I'm asking how do you properly draw on the image so that this stretching does NOT occur.

Comment: And I'm asking _you_ to show what _you're_ doing and what _your_ issue is, in _your own_ question, so we can grapple with that.

Comment: My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412987/swift-draw-on-image-without-changing-its-size